# Iterate through Object of arrays to display in a table

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an object returned from an API call and I an trying to show the object details in a table in HTML. I am able to get the key but not getting the values. I am using angular 7.

I have tried let keys = `Object.keys(successMsg.body.result);` which gives me `"ABC"`, how do I get the othet values?

In the HTML I am using :

```
<tbody> 
<tr *ngFor="let data of dataToShow | keyvalue"> 
<td> {{data.key}} </td> 
<td> {{data.value}} </td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```

The api data is: `{ "ABC": [ "1234567" ], "XYZ": [ "5678912" ] }`

Comment: In the HTML I am using :
         <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let data of dataToShow | keyvalue">
                  <td>
                    {{data.key}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{data.value}}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>

The api data is:

 {
        "ABC": [
            "1234567"
        ],
        "XYZ": [
            "5678912"
        ]
    }

Comment: Please click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59135134/edit) button below the question and update the code there instead of adding it in a comment

Comment: Please show us your object which you are gettnig from the API

Comment: @YogeshMali It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here.. your HTML looks valid

Comment: I don't see any issue with the given code, also working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wrs7e. Did you check if you have any console error?

Answer (score 0):

To access both the key and values at the same time you can do:

```js
Object.entries(successMsg.body.result);
```

This return an array per key/value pair. The key is the first element and the value's the second.

```js
const result = { "ABC": [ "1234567" ], "XYZ": [ "5678912" ] };

const entries = Object.entries(result);

console.log(entries);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the component get the keys of the object by

```js
this.data = successMsg.body.result;
this.keys = Object.keys(successMsg.body.result);
```

In Table, loop through the data

```html
<tbody> 
<tr *ngFor="let val of keys"> 
<td> {{val}} </td> 
<td> {{data[value][0]}} </td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```

If there is only one value in the array object above you can use the above code, but if there is more value in the value object you might have to loop through it

Answer (score -1):

To access the values

```
Object.values(successMsg.body.result); // Returns [[ "1234567" ], [ "5678912" ]]
```

```js
var result = { "ABC": [ "1234567" ], "XYZ": [ "5678912" ] };

console.log("****Keys****");
console.log(Object.keys(result));

console.log("****Values****");
console.log(Object.values(result));
```